# Estimating Pearson correlation for multivariate t distribution using Kendall rank correlation

Tags: correlation, kendall-tau, multivariate-distribution

I had a task to generate a certain amount of samples for $(X_{1},X_{2})$ with a bivariate $t$ distribution $t_{2}(\nu,\mu,\Sigma)$ and then estimate Pearson's correlation coefficient $\rho$ by using the Kendall rank correlations 
$$\rho_{\tau}(X_{1},X_{2})=\frac{2}{\pi}arcsin(\rho)$$

I got a really good estimation, close to the desired.
But what I was curious about is if I had a d-variate $t$ distribution (d>
2), would I have some problems with estimating the correlation?

The correlation matrices need not be positive definite, however the sample correlation matrix, if computed in exact arithmetic without a roundoff error can not have negative eigenvalues.
So if we want our correlation matrix to be positive semidefinite, we may run into problems if there are different sets of complete pairs for different pairs of variables (e.g. the missing values don't correspond).
Would that be a problem or maybe something with calculation of Kendall's rank correlation?